# How to pass array of functions to HOC function without losing initial typing in typescript?

Tags: typescript

After some digging I managed to figure out how some functions like **useCallBack** manage to take a function, do something with it, and then return your function, WITHOUT messing with the typing, so you won't get confused about the arguments you used to require.

this is what i came up with in my first scenario, in case of a single function being passed.

```
function doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks<T extends (...args: any) => any>(arg: T){
    //do magic
    return arg
};


function basicFunction(number:number){
    return number.toString();
}
function anotherFunction(){
    
}

const basicFunctionButWithMagic = doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks(basicFunction);
```

but thats not quite what i need, i actually also want to add in another scenario, where i pass an array of functions, and get back the same array with the arrays in the same order and have each function know its type and expected arguments.

so i tried this, but it didnt work.

```
function doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks<T extends (...args: any) => any>(arg: T | T[]){
    if(isArray(arg)){
        //do magic to each
        return arg as T[];
    }
    else {
        //do magic to one
        return  arg as T;
    }
};


function basicFunction(number:number){
    return number.toString();
}
function anotherFunction(){
    
}

const basicFunctionButWithMagic = doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks(basicFunction);

const [firstFunction,secondFunction] = doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks([basicFunction,anotherFunction]);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type FnType =  (...args: any) => any

function doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks<T extends FnType>(arg: T): T
function doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks<T extends FnType[]>(arg: T): T
function doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks(arg: FnType[] | FnType){
    if(Array.isArray(arg)){
        //do magic to each
        return arg 
    }
    else {
        //do magic to one
        return  arg 
    }
};


function basicFunction(number:number){
    return number.toString();
}
function anotherFunction(){
    
}

const basicFunctionButWithMagic = doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks(basicFunction);

const [firstFunction,secondFunction] = doMagicToCallBackOrCallBacks([basicFunction,anotherFunction]);
```

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work i get "const firstFunction: ((number: number) => string) | (() => void) | (((number: number) => string) | (() => void))[]"

Comment: Let me edit this answer because I think overloading is going to give you much better type safey.

Comment: Done, that should do the trick

Comment: Amazing! i have learned something new, thanks a lot my friend.